# jquery ajax and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Does anybody know how to execute javascript functions in an html that is loaded via ajax? I mean the html contains both plain text and javascript. In my case it seems that only the in-line javascript (eg. onclick="dosomething();return false") gets executed. The pre-defined functions which are wrapped by < script   language     = "javascript     >are unfortunately ignored..

i have search couple articles through the site but the results are either use getScript to load a pure js or use eval. please help me out of this! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### File 1:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test() {
  alert('i got loaded dynamically!');
}
</script>
```

#### File 2:

```
$.get('file1.html', function(html) {
  $(document).append(html);
  test(); // alerts "i got loaded dynamically!"
});
```

[See it in action](http://jsbin.com/idela).

Answer (score 2):

According to [the doco](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options), if you use `$.ajax` and specify a data type of `"html"`, included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM. Make sure your server is returning the correct data type, see [Specifying the Data Type for AJAX requests](http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests) for more info

If that doesn't help, Artem's approach also works well, providing you only make the request **once**. If you are making the same `$.get` call over and over, you'll end up with multiple copies of yourFunctionCall in the head, and Strange Things will happen :-)

Answer (score 0):

Look up jquery event delegation, and the .live() method.

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn

Event delegation is especially useful and efficient if you're working with a large piece of html that you've added dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this fixes your problem... but if your loaded html also includes a link to jquery's code base, it can cause issues with the child-code not correctly linking with the handle to the jquery object ($).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you receive from your AJAX call plain HTML mixed with javascript code, e.g. with  tags. I'm didn't checked it, but you can try to do the following:

```
$.get( ajaxURL, function( data)
{
   $( "head").append( $( data).find( "script"));
   yourFunctionCall( );
});
```